# From One Storyboard to another

Tags: iphone, sdk

For Example, I have 2 Storybards.  In the first Storyboard I have a View with a button and when you press the button the second storyboard should appear.

How can I do that?

Comment: Try not to mix things up, storyboard work like xibs and their function is to 'hold' the actual visual objects that are relevant to your app such as UIViewControllers and UIViews.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the docs for [the storyboard class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

You can create a storyboard using

```
UIStoryBoard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"secondStoryboard" bundle:nil];
```

and get view controllers from it like

```
UIViewController *initialViewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
```

or

```
UIViewController *otherViewcontroller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"otherController"];
```

Once you've got your view controllers you can just push them onto your navigation controller I guess.

However, I don't know what will happen with using two storyboard objects in the same view hierachy - it's probably fine but you never know :)

Answer (score 0):

Even though your question is a bit confusing, I think I know what you are trying to do.

You want to use two storyboards. [UIStoryboard](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has a method to retrieve an instance of any storyboard with a given name. So first, set a name for your storyboards and view controllers in Xcode and then load them up, and then from within any view controller:

```
UIStoryboard *anotherStoryboard = [UIStoryBoard storyboardWithName:@"SomeStoryboardName" bundle:nil];
```

Afterwards, instantiate the desired UIViewController from any storyboard:

```
UIViewController *anotherViewController = [anotherStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SomeViewControllerName"];
```

You could then push it into your navigation stack, for instance:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:anotherViewController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifided to be generic here's the way I do this in my app...

```
UIStoryboard *alternateStoryboard;

if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    alternateStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Alternate_iPad" bundle:nil];
} else {
    alternateStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Alternate_iPhone" bundle:nil];
}

AlternateController *altController = [alternateStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
[altController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
[self presentModalViewController:altController animated:YES];
```

If your app is only iPhone or iPad that can be reduced to...

```
UIStoryboard *alternateStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Alternate" bundle:nil];

AlternateController *altController = [alternateStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
[altController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
[self presentModalViewController:altController animated:YES];
```

You'll probably want to change the last 2 lines to suit the presentation style that you want.

Comment: I already made two Storyboards, but I want to switch from the First storyboard to the second storyboard.

Anyway, thanks!

Comment: That's where the last couple of lines, or some varient that suits the transition you want, come in. That part of it is really quite like switching between view controllers with Nibs.